# LightSwitch error when trying to use the runtime Design Screen feature

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch

I get the following error, when trying to use the runtime screen editor. (LightSwitch 2011, RTM version)

"The last change wasn't successfully persisted. Please shut down the running application. Error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

This happens after making any change and saving. I've tried creating a new project with a single table and a single screen. Same error.

Comment: Found the solution.  
Delete the following directories:  
%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\ComponentModelCache  
%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\ManifestCache  
  
Found the answer [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/lightswitch/thread/99ce68e8-52b1-4bd5-b298-7f9159d18ff7#25097ab9-f828-4cdb-97de-34b5c7aa9d50)

Comment: You should answer this question below so it can be flagged as answered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution. Delete the following directories:

```
%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\ComponentModelCache
%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\ManifestCache
```

Source [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/lightswitch/thread/99ce68e8-52b1-4bd5-b298-7f9159d18ff7#25097ab9-f828-4cdb-97de-34b5c7aa9d50).